# How do I stop Visual Studio from running as administrator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

This morning I set the `devenv.exe` to run as administrator. We are now getting problems with TFS and want to stop the Visual Studio running as admin. However even though I have disabled all of the checkboxes markes 'run as administrator' on the `devenv.exe` when I start VS it always runs as administrator. How do I now turn this off?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? If you're using Windows 8, it's not as simple as just disabling checkboxes.

Comment: What I've tried already: Ensuring all of the checkboxes (in the properties of the Visual Studio shortcut) relevant to 'run as administrator' are unchecked; There is a path in the windows directory which can prepend shortcut paths to run in admin mode, I've made sure that isn't there either.; I've checked devenv.exe itself to make sure there are no run as admin options selected on that file.

Comment: What is your User Account Control (UAC) setting?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure when you change the run as admin, you change it for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the icon and go to properties. After that just go to the Compatibility windows and in the Privilege Level un-check: "Run these program as administrator".

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  Of course based on your history.  You likely won't have an account in a few minutes.